# Quartz Scheduler not inserting records in DB using JDBCStore

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Configured Quartz job,

```
public static void schedule(IEntity entity, Date startdate) {
    try {
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(StatingUpdateJob.class)
                .withIdentity("UpdateStagingRecords" + entity.getId(), "StgToProduction").build();
        JobDataMap data = new JobDataMap(new HashMap<>());
        data.put("Entity", entity);
        job.getJobBuilder().setJobData(data);

        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        Date enddate = new Date();
        enddate.setTime(startdate.getTime() + 6000000);
        CronTrigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("UpdateStagingRecords" + entity.getId(), "StgToProduction").startAt(startdate)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *")
                        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .endAt(enddate).build();
        Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection("myDS");
        System.out.println(connection);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, cronTrigger);
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And then placed the quartz.properties in my class path

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=JavacodeGeeksScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=99199
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export=false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy=false
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=3
org.quartz.context.key.QuartzTopic=QuartzPorperties
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobListener.NAME.class=com.javacodegeeks.quartz.MyJobListener
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=admin
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=admin
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=30
```

My job is successfully created and triggering properly. But however the job details are not placing in DB. Here is my tables

[image]

Not sure what else I have to configure.

Comment: In the configuration last 5 properties are used for checking the configuration file at a fixed interval, I am not sure but are you using it ? If not then try commenting them out.

Comment: @BilboBaggins You mean the datasource related stuff ? That is the place where we can give the DB details ? Isn't it ? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Not sure what version and options you have for MYSQL, but it can have to do with uppercase problem. Your tables start with lowercase qrtz, and in your configuration you have this QRTZ_.

Comment: yep you are right my bad, I mixed up two views

Comment: @pringi gimme 2 min. I'll test that right away.

Comment: @pringi Tried and no luck. :( Nothing inserted into DB.

Comment: Can you access mySql directly (using workbench for example) and query the tables with uppercase and check if it is found (ex : Select * from QRTZ_LOCKS)?. Also can you trace Quartz to check what is happening. put quartz package in trace to see what is happening.

Comment: Also try changing this jdbc:mysql://localhost/test to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test (if mySql is running on 3306 port)

Comment: @pringi Yes SQL is able to access with both upper and lower case table names. What do you mean by `put quartz package in trace` ?

Comment: If you use some logging mechanisms like log4j then create the configuration for for logging to put org.quartz in trace, so you can check in the logs what can be the problem. (example: http://www.entroducing.com/view/create-new-log-file-with-log4j-fileappender-when-using-quartz-scheduler)

Comment: @pringi Sure. Thanks for the points. Checking the localhost thing first.

Comment: I have this configuration working in one of the examples I created for quartz: http://pastebin.com/FHLqE4iA

Comment: @pringi and Bilbo Thankyou so much. It's problem with port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that quartz datasource URL is not accepting as same as native jdbc url.

When I changed `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test`  to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

IT WORKED (thanks to *@pringi* and *@Bilbo Baggins*).